# Excel - nestle 3 if statements into one each has multiple conditions to be met?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 if statements that each require 3 conditions to be met. Is it possible to put these into one statement, so it checks each one and performs the actions when it sees the right one, for example:

```
IF((AND(A2="NIKE", B2="LADIES", C2="Y")), D2*E2, "No")
IF((AND(A2="ADIDAS", B2="MENS", C2="Y")), D2*E2, "No")
IF((AND(A2="PUMA", B2="KIDS", C2="Y")), D2*E2, "No")
```

On their own these 3 work but I cannot put them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR with your and:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2="NIKE", B2="LADIES", C2="Y"),AND(A2="ADIDAS", B2="MENS", C2="Y"),AND(A2="PUMA", B2="KIDS", C2="Y")),D2*E2, "No")
```

---

Now, if you do not want the one to one relationship, (NIKE→LADIES,ADIDAS→MENS,...) but actually want any in A2 to be any of the three and B2 to be any of the three we can re-do it:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2={"NIKE","ADIDAS","PUMA"}),OR(B2={"LADIES","MENS","KIDS"}),C2="Y"),D2*E2, "No")
```

or

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A2,{"NIKE","ADIDAS","PUMA"},B2,{"LADIES";"MENS";"KIDS"},C2,"Y")),D2*E2, "No")
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. One more question, is there a way I can apply a different calculation to each. Let's say I needed to add a different percentages to each supplier. So Nike would be D2*E2*7, Adidas would be D2*E2*3, etc

Comment: @RichStevens yes but that is a new question.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks.